# Detecting packed 64-bit Windows Portable Executable (EXE) files

Tags: disassembly, windows, malware, pe, packers

What programs are the most useful to detect if a 64-bit PE file has been packed (main focus is on EXE files).
I am not interested in the packer used I would just like to know if the file is packed or not.

I am aware of various PE file properties such as checking entropy, imports, etc.
PeID is generally recommended but unfortunately does not support 64-bit files, is there a program that is similar and supports 64-bit files (I have a large number of files to be checked)? Any other advise to solve this problem?

I have come across a few programs but I am not sure if they are good.

Comment: [Detect It Easy](http://ntinfo.biz/index.php/detect-it-easy) supports 64-bit PE files.

Answer (score 2):

protectionid supports x64 files no problem... and if you can think of anything i could add to it, just let me know and i'll see what i can do (new build is planned for halloween and it'll be a spooky 'theme').. just dont tell anyone, its a secret

Comment: what version was the first to support PE32+ ?

Comment: hmm, version 6, or possibly version 5, its supported pe32+ for quite some time

Comment: does protectionid use the features of the file (entropy, number of imports, etc) as well or is it only signature based?

Comment: its a lot more than signature based, entropy, imphash, analysis of sections, characteristics and so on... its a bit more than just the simple ep signature scan other scanners do

Answer (score 1):

I am only aware of two more packer detectors, [Protection iD](http://pid.gamecopyworld.com/), and DiE(Detect it Easy) as Extreme Coders has mentioned.

However you are on to something. 64-bit reverse engineering is still in its infancy, apart from IDA, tools are just now being developed to work on 64-bit applications, as it is a new architecture(relative to the number of 64bit applications out there), and on Windows in particular, comes with its own set of quirks(Driver signing, PatchGuard) which significantly slows a reversing down.
But even IDA have not yet released a 64-bit decompiler(though they claim it is almost ready) which is further confirmation of what I said.

Comment: [IDA 6.6 already has a x64 decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/6.6/)

Comment: Ah thanks for catching that, but this is IDA 6.6, x64 has been around for over a decade(though only recently did its use start to go up). My point still stands that 64-bit RE is still in its infancy.

Comment: @farmvde - "My point still stands that 64-bit RE is still in its infancy". You've only asserted the point, not provided evidence to support it. While there may not be *as many* 64-bit RE tools, it does not mean it is in its infancy. There are many RE tools supporting 64-bit (radare2, Hopper, IDA Pro, x64_dbg, WinDbg, gdb, Visual DuxDebugger, Capstone, diStorm64, C4Decompiler, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I use the following ones:

- [RDG](http://www.rdgsoft.net/)
- [DiE](https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy)
- [Yara](https://github.com/plusvic/yara) with [this](https://github.com/radare/radare2/tree/master/shlr/yara) set of rules
- [this](http://handlers.dshield.org/jclausing/packerid.py) Python script that uses PEiD rules (like [this](http://research.pandasecurity.com/blogs/images/userdb.txt) one).