# Does PeID signatures work with 64-Bit Portable Executable (EXE) files?

Tags: disassembly, windows, executable, x86-64, packers

Can the signatures from PeID be used on 64-Bit Portable Executable (EXE) files? 
PeID does not support 64-Bit files but I can use the signatures in another application with 64-Bit support.

My main interest is detecting 64-Bit EXE files that are packed.
This question is related to another question I have:

[Detecting packed 64-bit Windows Portable Executable (EXE) files](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6208/detecting-packed-64-bit-windows-portable-executable-exe-files)

Answer (score 2):

PEiD rules are only patterns, you can use them on whatever fileformat you want. Since PEiD is not maintained anymore, you may want to [export](https://github.com/jvoisin/yara_rules/blob/master/peid_to_yara.py) your rules to another format, like [yara](https://plusvic.github.io/yara/).

Comment: So would the the same packer have the same pattern on both 32-bit and 64-bit files or would the pattern change?